# (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I am using docker 19.03.6, docker-compose 1.25.3 and ubuntu 18. When I run `docker-compose up` the web container works, but mysql container is not **reachable**. What can I do?

The problem can be the **mysqlclient** package?

My Python code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="DBM", port=3306)
```

Note : I already tried src_db_1 instead of localhost!

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /api_rest_mix_1_0
WORKDIR /api_rest_mix_1_0
ADD requirements.txt /api_rest_mix_1_0/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /api_rest_mix_1_0/
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'DBM'
       MYSQL_USER: 'root'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app_dir
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Requirements.txt:

```
Django==3.0.3
mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

My commando on terminal : `docker-compose up`
Output from my command :

```
Creating network "src_default" with the default driver
Creating src_db_1 ... done
Creating src_web_1 ... done
Attaching to src_db_1, src_web_1
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.29-1debian9 started.
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.29-1debian9 started.
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:18.929128Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:22.350394Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:23.042973Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:23.291068Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 3d632fc3-530a-11ea-9cd8-0242ac140002.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:23.361130Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:24.557385Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  | 
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | February 19, 2020 - 11:23:25
web_1  | Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'api_rest_mix_1_0.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:25.254876Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.925550Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.927341Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29) starting as process 81 ...
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.932133Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.932155Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.932160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.932164Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.932168Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.932172Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.932473Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.932591Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.934281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.946320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.948809Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:43.960693Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.063103Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.063192Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.347746Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.348505Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.348523Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.348922Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.29 started; log sequence number 2630649
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.349095Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.349223Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.350675Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200219 11:23:44
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.354928Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.354950Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.355643Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.355680Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.393563Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.420138Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1   | 2020-02-19T11:23:44.420413Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '5.7.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
web_1  | Internal Server Error: /api/statistics/4
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1  |     response = get_response(request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 171, in statistics
web_1  |     json_response = stt_sex_status_total()
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 99, in stt_sex_status_total
web_1  |     db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="DBMix_hml", charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
web_1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
web_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
web_1  | [19/Feb/2020 11:23:45] "GET /api/statistics/4 HTTP/1.1" 500 82444
web_1  | Internal Server Error: /api/statistics/4
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1  |     response = get_response(request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 171, in statistics
web_1  |     json_response = stt_sex_status_total()
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 99, in stt_sex_status_total
web_1  |     db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="DBMix_hml", charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
web_1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
web_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
web_1  | [19/Feb/2020 11:23:46] "GET /api/statistics/4 HTTP/1.1" 500 82444
web_1  | Internal Server Error: /api/statistics/4
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1  |     response = get_response(request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 171, in statistics
web_1  |     json_response = stt_sex_status_total()
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 99, in stt_sex_status_total
web_1  |     db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="DBMix_hml", charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
web_1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
web_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
web_1  | [19/Feb/2020 11:23:47] "GET /api/statistics/4 HTTP/1.1" 500 82444
web_1  | Internal Server Error: /api/statistics/4
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1  |     response = get_response(request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 171, in statistics
web_1  |     json_response = stt_sex_status_total()
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 99, in stt_sex_status_total
web_1  |     db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="DBMix_hml", charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
web_1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
web_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
web_1  | [19/Feb/2020 11:23:47] "GET /api/statistics/4 HTTP/1.1" 500 82444
web_1  | Internal Server Error: /api/statistics/4
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1  |     response = get_response(request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 171, in statistics
web_1  |     json_response = stt_sex_status_total()
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 99, in stt_sex_status_total
web_1  |     db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="DBMix_hml", charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
web_1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
web_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
web_1  | [19/Feb/2020 11:23:47] "GET /api/statistics/4 HTTP/1.1" 500 82444
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
web_1  | Internal Server Error: /api/statistics/4
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1  |     response = get_response(request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 171, in statistics
web_1  |     json_response = stt_sex_status_total()
web_1  |   File "/api_rest_mix_1_0/api/views.py", line 99, in stt_sex_status_total
web_1  |     db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="DBMix_hml", charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
web_1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
web_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
web_1  | [19/Feb/2020 11:23:48] "GET /api/statistics/4 HTTP/1.1" 500 82444
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database DBMix_hml
db_1   | 2020-02-19 11:23:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user root
db_1   | ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
src_db_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: `db` as a hostname should work (the name of the service block in the `docker-compose.yml`).

Answer (score 1):

1. Change *host="localhost"* to  change *host="db"* like

   `db = MySQLdb.connect(host="db", user="root", passwd="password", db="DBM", port=3306)`
2. docker-compose.yml

   ```
   services:
     db:
       image: mysql:5.7
       ports:
         - '3306:3306'
       environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'DBM'
          MYSQL_USER: 'root'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
     web:
       build: .
       command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
       volumes:
         - .:/my_app_dir
       ports:
         - "8000:8000"
       depends_on:
         - db
       links: # <-- add this
         - db # <-- add this
   ```